# Is there a way to start Gazebo with a smaller window size?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Whenever I launch Gazebo from the command line, it isn't in fullscreen mode but the window is maximized and takes up the whole screen. Is there a way I can launch gazebo with a smaller window that doesn't take up the entire screen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12804/is-there-a-way-to-start-gazebo-with-a-smaller-window-size?/) by [sm02](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2425/sm02/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Open Gazebo, resize and reposition the window the way you want it to look when you open it, then on the top menu, choose:

`File` -> `Save Configuration`

The next time you open Gazebo, it will open that way ;)

Behind the scenes, Gazebo is updating the `~/.gazebo/gui.ini` file with geometry information like this:

```
[geometry]
width=1330
height=865
x=1148
y=418
```

You can also change these values manually if you'd like.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sm02](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2425/sm02/) on 2016-03-10**:
Great, thank you!